# Packages disappeared in Target Platform 2023-12

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

My Eclipse RCP application currently uses the `Target Platform 2023-09`, which is defined in the `2023-09.target` file as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?pde version="3.8"?>
<target name="Retrospective (2023-09)">
    <locations>
        <location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="planner" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
            <repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2023-09/"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.sdk.feature.group" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.platform.sdk" version="0.0.0"/>
        </location>
    </locations>
</target>
```

Now I try to upgrade to the recently released `Target Platform 2023-12` and created `2023-12.target` below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?pde version="3.8"?>
<target name="Retrospective (2023-12)">
    <locations>
        <location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="planner" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
            <repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2023-12/"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.sdk.feature.group" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.platform" version="0.0.0"/>
        </location>
    </locations>
</target>
```

After loading this new definition, the classes from the following packages cannot be found anymore.

- `org.eclipse.core.databinding.beans.*`
- `org.eclipse.jface.text.*`

No idea if these classes have been moved to different packages or if they got completely removed. I was also not able to find any helpful changelog for this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used

```
<unit id="org.eclipse.sdk.feature.group" version="4.30.0.v20231201-0512"/>
```

instead of `org.eclipse.platform`

For `org.eclipse.jface.text` I put that in the `feature.xml` for my own code and Tycho finds it.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. This indeed solves the problem with `org.eclipse.core.databinding.beans.*` but `org.eclipse.jface.text.*` can still not be found.

Comment: I also use that, I included it in my own feature.xml and Tycho seems to be able to find it.